# MS Access selecting records with a variable

Tags: ms-access, datetime

We are trying to make a query that has the user enter a date and the query pulls all records according to that date. In the Design View of the query we have tried [Enter Date] in criteria but it will not pull because it will match the date but not time. I have seen lots of dates formatted with ## marks to ignore the time yet I do not know how to incorporate that into our query.

Edit: Yes we are using Access which defaults to a date/time field.

We are impatient and are just going to do a range forcing the user to enter two dates. Honestly it takes care of two problems, but this was a frustrating issue with Access.

Comment: Sorry my solution did not work. There is still a method to have it work with only one user input. Gte the date through an inputbox and add it on the fly to your SELECT instruction before querying your data. You can do this with the recordset or the query object.

Answer (score 2):

So you have time stamps in the database that you want to query by a single date?

There are two ways to do this:

1) Strip off the time part on the database field

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table 
 WHERE DateValue([DateField]) = [Enter Date]
```

that's not very good performance wise but ok for small tables

2) you add times to your input date and use Between which is better performance wise

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE [DateField] BETWEEN [Enter Date] AND [Enter Date] + #23:59:59#
```

Comment: Thank you, Unfortunately it did not return any records

Comment: @DJ: Have you considered that the value for [Enter Date] may also have a time element that isn't midnight? I think you should round the [Enter Date] value down to midnight before adding #23:59:59#.

Comment: @onedaywhen: this is exactly why I generally don't use raw parameters -- it's too easy for the user to put in something you don't want. My bet is that users can't reliably type a valid date/time value with a time component. I'd tend to use a dialog form to pick the dates (complete with date picker) and that way I ve pre-validated the dates and don't need the parameters at all. Parameters get in the way when exposed directly to the user, it seems to me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your data was basically entered in a dateTime format. In this case, you should build your query on datevalue(myDateField) instead of building it on myDateField. Your query will then look like that (in the SQL window)

```
SELECT * From MyTable WHERE dateValue(myDateField) = [enter date here]
```

instead of

```
SELECT * From MyTable WHERE myDateField = [enter date here]
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it did not return any records

Answer (score 2):

I'd adjust DJ's suggestion about `BETWEEN`, because I never quite trust that it works the way I'd like it to (the reason for adding 1 second less than a day for the second value is because the second value is included in the `BETWEEN` range, which has always seemed counterintuitive to me).

Anyway, my suggestion:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table 
   WHERE [DateField] >= [Enter Date] 
         AND [DateField] < [Enter Date] + 1
```

It's not all that different, but it avoids the problem of adding the right amount to the second argument of `BETWEEN`. I am always wary of trying to do date/time math operations without using `DateAdd()` or `DateDiff()`.

Defining the parameter is a good idea, too, as then if a user puts in an invalid date, they'll get a useful error message, instead of just the wrong results.